# How do I access The Reef?

Tags: destiny

I can't find The Reef in House of Wolves. I bought the expansion, but every time i click on it, it just plays the trailer. Am I supposed to go on The Tower and get to it there or something?

Answer (score 3):

If you're just clicking the icon near The Tower, then that's just for the trailer.

When you progressed through the original story missions for Destiny, it took you to The Reef several times. It is located at the top of your map, between Venus and Mars. From there, you should have access to visit The Reef.

Of course, there are requirements to begin the first mission. You need to have completed the prior story missions and be at least level 24, though level 26 is needed to complete all of the story missions, and level 28 is recommended.

Comment: I don't think you need to have completed the prior story missions first. I've been leveling up a hunter, and when he reached level 20 and I equipped some gear I had saved up for him (making him level 27), I got a message that the Reef was open to me. At that point I had either just finished Venus or the first mission on Mars.

Answer (score 3):

Below shows screenshots on getting to the reef while you are in orbit, but also how to get to the Vestian Outpost, which is what I believe you are really looking for. I think you are looking for the new social location where you can see the new vendors. Please correct me if I am wrong.

[image]
[image]